# Module '"primeng/utils"' has no exported member 'FilterUtils'

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

After upgrading Angular to v15 I am getting this error:

> Module '"primeng/utils"' has no exported member 'FilterUtils'.

Is there any alternative of filtering like this without code changes?

```
import { FilterUtils } from 'primeng/utils';

filterStatus(event: Switch, dt: Table): void { 
  this.showErrorOnly = event.checked;
  if (event.checked) {
    dt.value = FilterUtils.filter(this.data, ['validation.status'], 'INVALID', 'contains');
  } else {
    dt.value = this.data;
  }
  dt.reset()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilterUtils` were [removed](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/229bb9420fcf7f406e314984a7f064e33640e71f/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L1549) in PrimeNG 11 and the [`FilterService`](https://primeng.org/filterservice) class was provided as the replacement:

```
import { FilterService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [FilterService] // you can also provide it globally in the AppModule
})
class SomeComponent {
  constructor (private readonly filterService: FilterService) {}

  filterStatus(event: Switch, dt: Table): void { 
    this.showErrorOnly = event.checked;
    if (event.checked) {
      dt.value = this.filterService.filter(this.data, ['validation.status'], 'INVALID', 'contains');
    } else {
      dt.value = this.data;
    }
    dt.reset();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `import { FilterUtils } from 'Primeng/utils';` is deprecated in **PrimeNg** version 11. If you are looking for something without a code change. I suggest you to downgrade the version of primeNg to `v10.0.0(lts)` Please find the official **PrimeNg v10** documentation [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v10-lts/#/setup).